# WEB SQL SELECT TOP 1 error

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

I keep getting an error when I try to add in a `TOP 1` to my select statement. The SQL runs fine without the `TOP 1` so it got me thinking that `TOP` is not supported in WEB SQL but I can't find any documentation online.

Has anyone successfully used `TOP` in their WEB SQL?

**This Doesn't Work!**

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyForms WHERE laganRef IS NOT NULL', [], trySend, errorHandler);
```

**But This Works!**

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM MyForms WHERE laganRef IS NOT NULL', [], trySend, errorHandler);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Steven

Answer (score 5):

I believe WEB SQL uses `LIMIT` instead of `TOP`. So this should work:

`'SELECT * FROM MyForms WHERE laganRef IS NOT NULL LIMIT 0,1'`

Answer (score 0):

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM MyForms WHERE laganRef IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1'
                                                           , [], trySend, errorHandler);
```

try this...

Answer (score 0):

**LIMIT 0,1** worked fine for me.

```
SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE1 LIMIT 0,1;
```